Oracle Cloud OCI: ssh from one Virtual Machine to another
I am on a Free Tier Oracle Cloud account. I created 2 Virtual Machines (VM) with Standard A1 Flex shape running Ubuntu 22.4 arch64. Both have the same subnet VNIC, with all Ingress and Egress ports opened. I also setup ssh key for them so that I can ssh to both from my local machine. I can see that each VM is assigned a public IP and a private IP.
Now I need to copy a file from one VM to the other, however pinging VM2 from VM1 doesn't work, on both public and private IP. How can I set the two VMs accessible to each other, so that scp/ssh/rsync from one to the other works?

Please check the private IPv4 addresses of both machines. Are they on the same network? Are both machines on the same data center?

It turns out that I can still ssh from one machine to another, despite ping fails. All I need is to create SSH key pairs on both machines and add the public key of one machine to the authorized list on the other; after that ssh using private IP will just work. I think there is some IP rules somewhere that disable pinging, but it doesn't matter.
